# Using QField Relation Reference for Attribute Table?

Tags: qfield

I would like to relate an attribute class to a point class by relation reference. In QField this is supported, but I can't open the attribute class yet. By selecting the point in the graphic I get the attributes of the point class with the attribute of the relation reference. But I didn't find a way to open the attribute class via the relation reference. Only in edit mode can I add a new entry in the attribute class via the relation reference. But once the record in the attribute class is added, there doesn't seem to be any way to edit the record again. Only a new one can be generated.

Anybody have an idea how it works?